# visual studio code maximize button doesn't work windows11

Tags: visual-studio-code

i cant resize window using maximize icon

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a reported issue, see [Maximize/restore button is not responsive when Window Controls Overlay is enabled](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159851).

You can try disabling this setting (although it is disabled by default in Stable v1.71) to see if it helps:

```
Window > Experimental > Window Controls Overlay: Enabled
```

Comment: It seems to help, first go to File/Preferences/Settings or just hit Ctrl+,

Comment: As a temporary workaround, in Windows you can also right-click the VS Code icon in the upper left corner and choose Maximize/Restore.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the F11 button? or the combination of CTRL + k -> Z
Bye

Comment: I have no problem with shortcuts or double click nav bar but the middle button doesn't work now

Comment: Yes but using the shortcut can be a temporarly nice solution, in order to use the middle button that you want use, you can also use the shortcut Win + arrows

Comment: This helped me much. I didn't press F11, but it was fullscreen. I dunno why. After pressing F11 I got a useful interface back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows 11 as well, and I just recently updated my vs code to the latest version.
I will use pictures to explain my solution

```
1. Go to settings
```

[image]

```
2. Search for overlay in the settings page
```

[image]

```
3. Uncheck the checkbox below and restart vs-code
```

[image]